# PHP file not being executed from post-commit

Tags: php, svn, bash

I have this in post-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

/usr/bin/php /home/name/svn/scripts/post-commit.php $REPOS $REV
```

But whatever I do, post-commit.php isn't being executed, not even with a chmod a+rw on it. Also there is no output from exec.

What am I missing?

**Update:** removed exec > ./logs/log.txt from this example since it seems to confuse people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"

#debug:
echo "------------------------------"
date >> /tmp/debug.txt
echo "$@" >> /tmp/debug.txt
id >> /tmp/debug.txt
env >> /tmp/debug.txt

/usr/bin/php /home/name/svn/scripts/post-commit.php "$REPOS" "$REV" > /full/path/to/log.txt 2>&1
```

Also, verify that your post script works fine when executed by hand.

Comment: Made the change. By hand it works, on commit it fails (post-commit hook failed (255 with no input)) :(

Comment: If it works by hand, then it's probably issue with perms or environment. Study debug output (see updated post). The 255 exit code is usually in fatal error like syntax error.

Comment: This is the output:

Sun Sep 11 08:33:05 CDT 2011
/home/name/svn/xxx 37
uid=32289(the_user) gid=32292(the_user) groups=32292(the_user)
PWD=password
SHLVL=1
_=/bin/env

What does this tell you? (I'm not sure what this means)

Comment: When executed from the command line the debug information contains a lot more variables. Does this mean anything?

Comment: From the command line there's this: _=/usr/bin/env

While from the post-commit it's _=/bin/env

Comment: without post-commit.php content it's hard to tell what's wrong. Sorry. You can try `sudo su - the_user` and unset unneded variables to reproduce problem when executing by hand. You may see some hins then. Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your script.

Comment: post-commit.php contains nothing more than a mail() function to test if the file is being executed. It's preceded by #!/usr/bin/php.

Comment: Ok, weird. I got it working (the idea is to update the database on commit), but the mail() function still isn't working. It's just there as a test so I don't really need it, but it's still strange it's not being executed. So for now I'm good. Thank you for your time and expertise!

Answer (score 1):

`exec` replaces the current shell process, and doesn't start a new one. So after the `exec` command, your shell stops.

The purpose of your particular `exec` command eludes me by the way ... So just remove it and you should be fine.

Comment: No, it isn't that. I read somewhere that exec writes the output to a file so that's why it's there.

post-commit.php isn't executed without the addition of exec. I have this problem in other bash scripts too where I try to execute a php file. It works fine from the command line though.

Comment: Right ... exec also seems to serve a dual-function in the ability to reset stdout to a file ... How very un-UNIX! Anyway ... How are you executing this hook? from your description, I suspect something is going wrong there, and not with the actual script.

Comment: It's executed on an svn commit.

Answer (score 0):

you'd better to exec a 'cd' first, to a directory where you really want the shell to execute.
i'm not sure the path SVN will have when running this, but of course your script have potential privilege problems